# Negative lookahead - End of string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Given strings that look similar to this:

```
string = "!([!x0]|[x1&x2])"
```

I am writing a regular expression that matches any xi where i is a digit within a given range, that is **not** followed by | or & or ) or ]

```
r'x[0-range](?![\|\&\)\]])'
```

It works, except when xi is at end of string:

```
string = "x0&x1"
```

it matches "x1" which is not wanted. Not sure how to modifiy this. Help?

Comment: Try replacing `(?![\|\&\)\]])` with `(?=[^]|&)])`

Comment: Thanks, this works for `xi`, but for instance, if I have `&` at the end of the string that I want to match, then postive lookahead `&(?=[^x!])` doesn't work, while equivalent negative `&(?![x!])` does. Why does this happen?

Comment: Sorry, your question is rather vague. First, what is `range`? If it is a 2+ digit number, then it won't work since `[...]` is a *character* class. Second, what are the real, final requirements? If you need to match something not at the end of string and when not followed with some chars, there are 2 ways: `(?!x|$)` or `(?=[^x])`. `&(?=[^x!])` matches `&` and then *requires* a char other than `x` immediately to the right of `&`. The negative lookahead only fails the match if its pattern matches.

Comment: Does https://regex101.com/r/NSACbT/1 work for your general case? (I mean the question, not the comment above).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that `range` in `[0-range]` can only be a single digit, it won't work for 2+ digit numbers since it is a [single] *character* class.

Next, negative lookaheads allow matching at the end of string *implicitly*, that is, if you do not specify the `|$` (or similar) alternative inside the lookahead.

Thus, you may turn `(?![\|\&\)\]])` into `(?![\|\&\)\]]|$)` (or, as the very end of string in Python `re` is specified with `\Z` - `(?![\|\&\)\]]|\Z)`).

It is not efficient to use alternations in regex patterns, and there is another approach that helps you achieve what you need without adding an alternative: *convert the negative lookahead with a positive character class to a positive lookahead with a negated character class*.

In this case, `(?![\|\&\)\]])` turns into `(?=[^\|\&\)\]])`, i.e. we require that there must be a character other than `|`, `&`, `)` or `]` immediately to the right of the current location.

Note that in Python regex patterns, the `(?=[^\|\&\)\]])` pattern can be written without backslashes: `(?=[^]|&)])`. If you are not comfortable with this, remember that you only may need to escape `]`, `\`, `^` and `-` inside a character class (`\` should always be escaped).